i declare multiple variables in the same line and the code goes haywire
This is the code:
# include<stdio.h>

int main(){
     int num1, num2, num3 = 9;

     printf("%d ", num1);
     printf("%d ", num2);
     printf("%d ", num3);
}

I obviously expected the output to be 9 9 9 but the actual output is : 0 13637000 9.
Why is it happening?

Welcome to SO. What compiler are you using? Did you get any warning about using variable num1 and num2 without assigning a value first? If not, you should increase warning level. For GCC and Clang you can use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic to get proper warnings. If you got some warnings, then you must learn, not to ignore them.

This is a good example why declaring multiple variables in one line is usually a bad practice.

There is a similar trap with say char* a, b, c; where only a is a pointer.

OT: int main() is invalid. Use int main( void ), if that's what you mean...

@Fe2O3 — that's not accurate.  The standard uses int main() in examples.  C23 complicates life even more.

this is explained in every C book. Read a good book first instead of trial and error then ask here

This is happening because you've declared the variable num1 and num2 without initialising it. So at the time when you're printing the variable they display whatever random values were in their respective memory locations at the time of execution.
To get the expected result of 9 9 9 you need to intialize both the variables like this:
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1 = 9, num2 = 9, num3 = 9;

    printf("%d ", num1);
    printf("%d ", num2);
    printf("%d ", num3);

    return 0;
}


int num1, num2, num3 = 9; initializes only num3. You need
int num1 = 9, num2 = 9, num3 = 9;

